# How to correctly implement processors for RUNTIME annotations (not for SOURCE)

Tags: java, annotations, runtime

I need some help with developing a processor for an annotation with RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME(on the analogy of @Deprecated). I seek for a solution in JavaSE environment regardless of Spring, Java EE and etc.

I understand next points for now:

1. com.sun.mirror.apt was deprecated and should not be used any more;
2. AbstractProcessor(subclass), file META-INF\source\javax.annotation.processing.Processor and an annotation itself all deployed in jar file and placed in the CLASSPATH of the main application(with Enabled annotation processing) work perfectly fine for RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;

However, am I right about:

3. the above mentioned approach with AbstractProcessor doesn’t work for
   RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME (or at least I can’t make it work);
4. for the reason of RUNTIME, the annotation processor implementing    InvocationHandler interface should be used([link](http://javadevtips.blogspot.ru/2011/10/full-working-runtime-annotation-example_30.html)).

Also, was the processor for @Deprecated developed by means of apt or InvocationHandler? I can’t  find the processor for this annotation in jdk.